# How to effectively use which() to compare one column and a row in r?

Tags: r

## Data

I have multiple vehicles data set, each with a unique ID, `Vehicle.ID2`. Following is part of the data for 1 vehicle only:

```
df <- structure(list(Vehicle.ID2 = c("4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", 
"4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", 
"4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2", "4-2"), Time = c(3, 3.2, 3.4, 
3.6, 3.8, 4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.6, 5.8, 6, 6.2, 
6.4, 6.6, 6.8), yposition = c(3.451, 7.357, 11.264, 15.171, 19.077, 
22.984, 26.89, 30.797, 34.704, 38.61, 42.517, 46.423, 50.33, 
54.236, 58.143, 62.05, 65.956, 69.863, 73.769, 77.676), LeadVehyposition2 = c(55.043, 
NA, 64.098, 68.626, 73.153, 77.681, 82.209, 86.736, 91.264, 95.791, 
100.319, 104.847, 109.374, 113.902, 118.429, 122.957, 127.485, 
132.012, 136.54, 141.067)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID2", "Time", 
"yposition", "LeadVehyposition2"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

## What I want to do

I want to compare the `LeadVehyposition2` with `yposition` in the `df` and output the first `Time` where the `yposition` is greater than or equal to `LeadVehyposition2`. With 1 vehicle, I can do this by using the following code for the 1st value in `LeadVehyposition2`:

```
df$Time[head(which(df$yposition>=55.043),1)]
> 5.8
```

Here, the first value in the `LeadVehyposition2` was 55.043 and I compared it with all the values in the `yposition`. I want to do the same with all values in `LeadVehyposition2`. Following is the code that didn't work for the whole data set (multiple Vehicle IDs):

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
group_by(Vehicle.ID2) %>% 
mutate(Time.PET = Time[head(which(yposition>=LeadVehyposition2),1)]%>%
ungroup()
```

## Problem:

The problem is that using the second piece of code compares the values of `yposition` and `LeadVehyposition2` by rows only. But, the objective is to keep `LeadVehyposition2` constant and compare it with the whole column of `yposition`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See `?findInterval`; e.g. apply in groups `df$Time[findInterval(df$LeadVehyposition2, df$yposition) + 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do it in `base`;

```
df$Time[sapply(df$LeadVehyposition2, function(p) min(which(df$yposition >= p)))]
 [1] 5.8  NA 6.2 6.4 6.6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Or:

```
with(df, Time[sapply(LeadVehyposition2, function(p) min(which(yposition >= p)))])
 [1] 5.8  NA 6.2 6.4 6.6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

To take care of the grouping by Vehicle issue:

```
df <- df[order(df$Vehicle.ID2, df$Time), ]
do.call(c, sapply(split(df, df$Vehicle.ID2), function(df) 
        with(df, Time[sapply(LeadVehyposition2, function(p) min(which(yposition >= p)))])))
```

Comment: Nice. I was trying to think of a way to make `?Position` work, but it's extraordinarily ugly - `df$Time[mapply(function(x,y) Position(function(x) x > y, x), df["yposition"], replace(df$LeadVehyposition2, is.na(df$LeadVehyposition2), Inf ))]`

Comment: Where is the grouping by vehicle id?

Comment: @eddi. Ahh, missed that, since the data OP gives only contains one vehicle.

Comment: @Psidom, Thanks! This was the simplest solution and worked for me. I used `do` in `dplyr` instead of `do.call`. The take home lesson for me is that if one variable is held constant and the other is varying then I can use function in `which()`.

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` method could be to join the `df` to itself, then take the minimum `Time` with a positive difference between `yposition` and `LeadVehyposition2`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

res <- df[ df[, .(Vehicle.ID2, Time, yposition)], on = c("Vehicle.ID2"), allow.cartesian=T][i.yposition - LeadVehyposition2 > 0, .(min(i.Time)), by = .(Vehicle.ID2, Time, LeadVehyposition2)]
res
#     Vehicle.ID2 Time LeadVehyposition2  V1
# 1:         4-2  3.0            55.043 5.8
# 2:         4-2  3.4            64.098 6.2
# 3:         4-2  3.6            68.626 6.4
# 4:         4-2  3.8            73.153 6.6
```

Joining this back onto `df` will add the extra column onto the original data

```
res[df, on = c("Vehicle.ID2","Time","LeadVehyposition2")]

#      Vehicle.ID2 Time LeadVehyposition2  V1 yposition
#  1:         4-2  3.0            55.043 5.8     3.451
#  2:         4-2  3.2                NA  NA     7.357
#  3:         4-2  3.4            64.098 6.2    11.264
#  4:         4-2  3.6            68.626 6.4    15.171
#  5:         4-2  3.8            73.153 6.6    19.077
#  6:         4-2  4.0            77.681  NA    22.984
# ...
# 17:         4-2  6.2           127.485  NA    65.956
# 18:         4-2  6.4           132.012  NA    69.863
# 19:         4-2  6.6           136.540  NA    73.769
# 20:         4-2  6.8           141.067  NA    77.676
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use rolling joins for this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# create an index to be used for matching
df[, idx := 1:.N, by = Vehicle.ID2]

# find the matching index using rolling joins
df[, idx.m := .SD[.SD, on = c('Vehicle.ID2', yposition = 'LeadVehyposition2'), roll = T,
                 idx + 1]][1:5]
#   Vehicle.ID2 Time yposition LeadVehyposition2 idx idx.m
#1:         4-2  3.0     3.451            55.043   1    15
#2:         4-2  3.2     7.357                NA   2    NA
#3:         4-2  3.4    11.264            64.098   3    17
#4:         4-2  3.6    15.171            68.626   4    18
#5:         4-2  3.8    19.077            73.153   5    19

# get the time for each match
df[, Time.PET := Time[idx.m], by = Vehicle.ID2][1:5]
#   Vehicle.ID2 Time yposition LeadVehyposition2 idx idx.m Time.PET
#1:         4-2  3.0     3.451            55.043   1    15      5.8
#2:         4-2  3.2     7.357                NA   2    NA       NA
#3:         4-2  3.4    11.264            64.098   3    17      6.2
#4:         4-2  3.6    15.171            68.626   4    18      6.4
#5:         4-2  3.8    19.077            73.153   5    19      6.6
```

If `yposition` and `LeadVehyposition2` can be strictly equal I would suggest adding very small (positive) jitter to `yposition` for the above to work correctly.

---

Another option, with the [latest development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table` adding non-equi joins, can be:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[df, on = .(Vehicle.ID2, yposition >= LeadVehyposition2), Time[1], by = .EACHI][1:5]
#   Vehicle.ID2 yposition  V1
#1:         4-2    55.043 5.8
#2:         4-2        NA  NA
#3:         4-2    64.098 6.2
#4:         4-2    68.626 6.4
#5:         4-2    73.153 6.6
```

Which reads - join `df` with itself on columns where `Vehicle.ID2` is the same and `yposition` is larger than or equal to `LeadVehyposition2`, then take the first `Time` for each "i" (aka the first argument of `[.data.table`).

And you can of course assign that as a column:

```
df[, Time.PET := .SD[.SD, on = .(Vehicle.ID2, yposition >= LeadVehyposition2),
                    Time[1], by = .EACHI]$V1]
```

**NOTE:** both answers assume that `yposition` is already sorted in increasing order.

Comment: with your second solution, how does the first `Time` (i.e. `Time[1]` - **take the first `Time` for each "i"**) ensure that it's the minimum `Time`. Does the order of `Time` matter here?

Comment: good question - the order of `yposition` is the one that matter I think, so more generally either need to order, or do smth like `Time[which(yposition == min(yposition))[1]]`

Comment: Like I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786675/replicating-ddply-with-the-dplyr-package-ddply-is-too-slow/36798796#comment61247092_36798796), non-equi joins aren't implemented to work with `by=.EACHI` yet. So I'd rather not provide answers using them until then.

Comment: @Arun since it's worked every time I tried so far, including here - can you give a quick example where it doesn't work?